# Mule 4 sftp read file - retry mechanism using Until successful , unable to catch exception

Tags: mule, mule4

This question is a followup to an earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72199441/mule-4-sftp-read-file-reconnection-strategy-not-working)

So:
Am trying to read a file from a SFTP location . Am using Mule 4.4 Community edition. If there is any error while connecting to SFTP server or file is not present , would like mule to retry 2 times .

Based on answer from @aled I am now using 'until successful'

Here is the code :

```
<sftp:config name="SFTP_Config" doc:name="SFTP Config">
        <sftp:connection host="abcd" username="xyz" password="pwd" />
    </sftp:config>

<flow name="get:employee">
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"  message="starting search" category="get-employee"/>
        <until-successful maxRetries="1" doc:name="Until Successful" millisBetweenRetries="30000">
                <sftp:read doc:name="Read"  config-ref="SFTP_Config" path="/a/employees.unl">
            <repeatable-in-memory-stream />
            <reconnect />
        </sftp:read>
       </until-successful>
        <error-handler ></error-handler>    
</flow>
```

Now the code is retrying to read file from sftp 1 time at an interval of 30 seconds .
All good till here

The bit that has got me confused is - error handling .
In my case I am testing without the file being present in sftp so I get the error :

> SFTP:ILLEGAL_PATH

However after max retries the error type is :

> SFTP:RETRY_EXHAUSTED

IN error handler when I give the type of error to catch as : SFTP:RETRY_EXHAUSTED
it is not getting caught !

```
<on-error-continue enableNotifications="false" logException="false" doc:name="On Error Continue" type="SFTP:RETRY_EXHAUSTED">
</on-error-continue>
```

when I give the catch block to catch both error types:
SFTP:RETRY_EXHAUSTED and SFTP:ILLEGAL_PATH

```
<on-error-continue enableNotifications="false" logException="false" doc:name="On Error Continue"  type=" SFTP:RETRY_EXHAUSTED,SFTP:ILLEGAL_PATH">
</on-error-continue>
```

The exception is caught but with a warning in log:

> Expected error type from flow 'get:employee/errorHandler/2' has
> matched the following underlying error: ILLEGAL_PATH. Consider
> changing it to match the reported error: RETRY_EXHAUSTED.

I am unable to understand this behaviour and what is the best way to do error handling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `SFTP:RETRY_EXHAUSTED` it is `MULE:RETRY_EXHAUSTED`. Try to catch `MULE:RETRY_EXHAUSTED` or simply `RETRY_EXHAUSTED` in the error handler.

You can refer to [until-success](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/until-successful-scope) documentation for more details.

The `RETRY_EXHAUSTED` error only wraps the **latest error** that failed the `until-success` scope, which is, in most cases, the one that you would want to know. You can get this error using `error.suppressedErrors[0]`.

For example:
If you want to do handle errors differently based on the latest error you can add a condition in the when expression of the error handler. Something like `error.suppressedErrors[0].errorType == SOME_ERROR_TYPE`